# Merge two if conditions

Tags: php

I have to implement some functionality for admin. For that i'm checking if the session is set for admin or not.

I have used two nested if statements for checking session variable as,

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['user_type']))
{
    if($_SESSION['user_type']== 'admin')
    {
          //functionality
    }
}
```

I dont have problem with above code. It works fine. But i want to know whether is there any way to write above logic within a single if statement.

if i write

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user_type']) && $_SESSION['user_type']== 'admin')
```

or

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user_type']) == 'admin')
```

it gives error if `$_SESSION['user_type']` is not set.

Is there any way to do it? Please help

Comment: Have you tried to check for admin first and isset second?

Comment: You can also use `array_key_exists`  to bypass this notice.

Comment: @michael : it definitely wont work, isset need to be checked first.

Comment: post your real code.

Comment: this will not give you the "error" (which is a notice, not an error/warning)  `if(isset($_SESSION['user_type']) && $_SESSION['user_type']== 'admin')`

Comment: `if(isset($_SESSION['user_type']) && $_SESSION['user_type']== 'admin'){}`
should work fine. Did for me.

Comment: I am agree with @Rufinus, `if(isset($_SESSION['user_type']) && $_SESSION['user_type']== 'admin')` should not give any error.

Comment: @Rufinus. yes,it was just a notice. Can i use it by ignoring that notice?

Comment: with the isset in front there shouldnt be a notice, see warren's answer on why.

Comment: yes got it.thanks everyone for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've written will work fine:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user_type']) && $_SESSION['user_type']== 'admin')
```

PHP uses [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) when evaluating boolean expressions, so `$_SESSION['user_type']== 'admin'` will only be evaluated if `isset($_SESSION['user_type'])` returns `true`, preventing an error being thrown.

It might be worthwhile to mention that `isset` will only return true if the key exists in the array **and** its value is not `null`, whereas `array_key_exists('user_type', $_SESSION)` will return `true` if the key exists, regardless of its value.

In this instance, it doesn't matter, but for future reference!

Answer (score -3):

I removed some small mistakes, please try this one:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user_type']) && $_SESSION['user_type'] === 'admin') {
```

Comment: it's the same thing you just altered the semantics a bit. the thing is, the oringinal question itself is pointless, as it lies about what the code does. it shouldn't give any error. trying to "fix" it gives the false impression that there's actually something wrong with that code. which isn't the case.

Comment: Just change to `===` ? I don't think it will solve the problem.